# Выполнение параллельных запросов при обращение к API (AXIOS, JS)

Tags: javascript, axios

Разрабатываю приложение на JS и есть необходимость обращения к api для получения записей. Но Api накладывает ограничение на количество одновременно получаемых записей не более 100 шт. это происходит следующим образом.

```
/**
* Данная функция делит ids на массивы по 100 шт.(так как api может вернуть только 100 записей)
* вызывает другую функцию, которая выполняет запросы.
* ожидает выполнения запроса, собирает всё в общий массив и отправляет результат
*/
const prepareRequest = async (ids) => {
    let items = [];
    while (ids && ids.length>0) {
        let tmpIds = ids.splice(0,100); // делим по на массивы по 100 записей
        let itemsTmp = await itemsRequest(tmpIds); // ожидаем получения результата
        items = [...items, ...itemsTmp]; // склеиваем массивы  
    }
    return items; // возвращаем результат
}

/**
* делает запрос к api ждёт выполнения и отдаёт результат
*/
const itemsRequest(ids) => async (ids) => {
    const response await axios.get('path/to/api', {
                         'params': {'ids': ids}
                         });
    if(response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
        return response.data;
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что запросы выполняются последовательно, а не параллельно.
Есть ли какой-то способ выполнить данные запросы (по 100 шт.) параллельно и при этом, чтобы функция `prepareRequest` возвращала полный массив данных, а не по 100 шт.

Comment: @AzizUmarov если честно, то после написания вопроса я уже нашёл решение через new Promise.all([массив вызовов функций]); прекрасно работает, но надеюсь, кто-то даст более оптимальное решение, чем написал я.

Comment: Promise all ожидает завершения всех промисов. Но это лишь асинхронные запросы. А не параллельные потоки нужно понимать разницу

Comment: @AzizUmarov возможно я неправильно выразился, но согласно дебагеру, они запускаются параллельно, и на данном этапе меня это устраивает.  P.S. в js новичок не судите строго.

Comment: Дам несколько определений. Не сужу просто даю понять что это разные вещи. И да вы правильно нашли Promise.all

Answer (score 1):

Дам несколько определений [отсюда](https://softwaremaniacs.org/blog/2011/10/10/asynchronous-vs-parallel/) и вырезку [отсюда](https://medium.com/@stasonmars/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-javascript-%D1%81-async-await-ba5f47f4436)

> ***Асинхронность*** говорит о порядке исполнения кода. Если вызываемая функция не возвращает значение сразу, а отдаёт управление вызывающему
> коду с обещанием выдать значение позже, то эта функция асинхронная.
> При этом нет никаких предположений о том, как это значение будет
> считаться: параллельно или нет.

> ***Параллельность*** говорит о том, что в машине физически происходит несколько процессов одновременно. При этом, с точки зрения кода
> программы это всё может выглядеть вполне синхронно. Например, если
> подряд вызываются две функции, то исполняющая среда может решить по
> каким-то признакам, что эти функции независимы, и выполнить их
> параллельно. С точки зрения программы этого заметно не будет.

> *JavaScript* сам по себе **однопоточный**, что означает то, что только один блок кода может запускаться за раз. Так как движок JS выполняет
> наш код, обрабатывая строку за строкой, он использует один стек
> вызова, чтобы продолжать отслеживать код, который выполняется в
> соответствии с установленным порядком. Тоже самое, что и делает стек —
> структура данных, которая записывает строки выполняемых инструкций и
> выполняет их в стиле LIFO, то есть Last In First Out, что переводится
> как, “последний пришел — первый обслужен”.

Вам же для вашего случая достаточно чтоб не блокировался поток (единственный) использовать [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) вот пример использования с библиотекой [axious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194036/async-await-not-working-as-expected-with-promise-all-and-a-map-function)